# How to get state reference from lambda with capture clause?

Tags: c++, lambda, closures, this, std

Lambdas can capture members from the context they are created in using the `[=]` syntax. I assume that there must be a state reference stored in the lambda, something like a `this` pointer.

```
class Class
{
public:
    void Function()
    {
        /*
         * pass this lambda expression as parameter to another
         * function and from there recover the this pointer which
         * would be of the type Class* for further usage.
         */

        [=](int)->int { /* do something with this->Member */ }
    }
private:
    int Member;
};
```

Is there a way to fetch the reference pointer from a lambda expression?

Comment: You can capture `this`: `[=, this](int)->int { }`

Comment: @jrok: `this` is already being captured. The question is, can the captured value be recovered from the lambda object?

Comment: After reading it a second time and understanding what you mean, it is indeed an interresting question. But I suppose not, since the mapping from `Member` to `captured_this_pointer->Member` inside the lambda function body is way behind the scenes, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot recover captured values or references from a lambda object.

The lambda type has no public data members, and the only public member functions are the function-call operator, constructors, destructors, assignment operators, and the conversion-to-function-pointer operator if it doesn't capture anything. None of these can be used to extract the captured entities.

Comment: @danijar: Unfortunately not; lambda types can't be extended. The closest you can get is to define a class with a function-call operator, a constructor and member variables to explicitly capture things, and whatever extended interface you need. You'd create that with class declaration syntax, `MyLambda(this)`, not lambda syntax.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what the simplest way is to pass the lambda as parameter to a function and access function pointer and state reference there? Of course I have to pass additional parameters then. By the way, what is the lambda type's actually name? Can I store it in a lambda type instead of say `std::function`?

Comment: @danijar: The lambda type has no name. However, you *can* pass it to a function without converting to `std::function` by making the function a template: `template <typename Lambda> void f(Lambda)`.

Comment: @danijar: If the entities are captured by value, then there is no way to access them; you'll have to define your own function class rather than a lambda if you need that. If they are captured by reference, then you could pass around your own references to the same objects.

Comment: So I have to pass my own reference as parameter to the lambda which wouldn't have a capture clause anymore, right? Is there a way to `std::bind` the reference to the lambda parameter so that I get a function pointer without reference parameter in the end?

Comment: Well, you could still make the lambda *return* the captured entity. Still this probably won't work with `this`, since you IMHO cannot directly use the captured `this` as an expression inside the lambda (or can you?).

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yes, you could use `this` inside the lambda. But presumably the lambda has a purpose other than returning the captured entity; if that's all you want it to do, then you wouldn't use a lambda at all.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Well, at least it is somehow partly possible to achieve what the OP wants. But of course you're right in that it isn't really flexible or how lambdas are supposed to be used. But I for myself thought the main problem of his approach was that he cannot get the `this` in the first place. Hadn't thought about accesing the captured entities from outside (apart from the lambda returning them or passing them to other functions) at all, since it was clear to me that's not possible. But in the end it seems your answer addresses the actual problem of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

To complement Mike's answer: you can actually recover any information stored in the lambda... by returning it on invocation (or storing it in out-parameters). It is even possible to capture a reference to a variable inside the lambda, bearing in mind that the reference is only usable as long as the lambda lives.

Of course, this might require altering the signature of the lambda.

```
[=](int i) -> std::pair<int, X*> {
    return std::make_pair(i, this);
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, could you provide an example, please?

Comment: I understand know, but I cannot execute the lambda to get the this pointer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @danijar If you can rewrite the lambda itself, you could "cleverly" make the entire body some kind of `if` statement to either return the captured element(s) or execute the "real" function the lambda represents....but that's almost certainly too clever to be a worthwhile programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this] instead of [=].

For further reference I suggest
http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html

Currently I tend to use [&] as a capture most of the time. It's cheap and normally lambda expressions are short enough so this is safe.